# Change CSV result of Image Pipeline on Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm using the default Scrapy Images Pipeline and I'm exporting my data as CSV. The last field is auto-filled with an array containing the original url, local path and checksum. However, I need to have just a string containing the local path. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting results like

```
item["images"] = [
  {'checksum': '2b00042f7481c7b056c4b410d28f33cf',
   'path': 'full/0a79c461a4062ac383dc4fade7bc09f1384a3910.jpg',
   'url': 'http://www.example.com/files/product1.pdf'}]
```

Inside your `process_item()` method of Pipeline, do this

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    images = item["images"]
    del item["images"]

    item['path'] = []
    for k,v in images.iteritems():
        item['path'].extend([v['path']])
```

Comment: According to https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#module-scrapy.pipelines.files I don't think I can extend process_item method. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not saying to extend that method ... You just have a ItemPipeline and inside that pipeline there will be a method `process_item`, just write the code I told you.

Comment: My bad, you're right. In this case item["images"] = item["images"][0].get("path") was enough but thanks for poiting me in the right direction! will approve the answer